# How to hide dates in GanttProject?

Tags: gantt

I'm building a Gantt chart using [GanttProject](https://www.ganttproject.biz). I'd like to hide the dates (that "rule" above the chart), I mean, not using real dates, but week 1, 2, 3 ou day 31, 32, 33 and so on, just to give a perception about how my team and me are organizing each activity in my project. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you got a downvote, as this seems like a reasonable tools question for a PM. However, you could probably improve your question with a screenshot and a little more explanation about what options you've already tried with your tool and why those didn't work for you. In the end, though, if it's not a widely-used tool you may have to ask the vendor for assistance with this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GanttProject support forum is here: http://forum.ganttproject.biz

Spoiler: no such feature in GanttProject. Existing enhancement request: https://github.com/bardsoftware/ganttproject/issues/85